# How can I edit the legend of a multiline ggplot graph in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I am plotting two data series with independent variables onto a single graph. While the plot looks great, I have no control of the legend. 
The files (raw data and plot) are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/clhguur6mu4855d/AAB_T7q5x5WvW5C9tveOH4XDa?dl=0).

The code is below:

```
ggplot()+  
geom_line(data = data_fluka,
          aes(x = depth_fluka, y = dose_fluka_norm, color = "blue"), size=1.01)+  
geom_line(data = data_geant,
          aes(x = depth_geant, y = dose_geant_norm, color = "red"), size=1.01)+  
    labs(size= "1", x = "Depth (mm)", y = "Normalised Dose",
         title = 'Dose Depth Comparison', vjust=-10)+  
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=0, vjust=1),
        axis.title=element_text(size=16), 
        legend.position="top")+  
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18))+
    ylim(c(0,1)) + xlim(c(0,25))+  
    scale_fill_discrete(name=" ", labels=c("GEANT4", "FLUKA"))
```

What I am able to get is in the linked folder above.

Comment: You are mapping to `color` but trying the change the nonexistent `fill` legend.  You'll need to switch to using `scale_color_*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend combining your data into one dataframe and stratifying by "type" (Fluka vs Geant4) for better control over the legend:

```
names(data_fluka) <- c("Depth", "NormalizedDose")
data_fluka$type  <- "FLUKA"

names(data_geant) <- c("Depth", "NormalizedDose")
data_geant$type  <- "GEANT4"

dat <- rbind(data_fluka, data_geant)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Depth, y = NormalizedDose))+  
     geom_line(size=1.01, aes(colour = type))+  
     labs(size= "1", x = "Depth (mm)", y = "Normalised Dose",
          title = 'Dose Depth Comparison', vjust=-10)+  
     theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16),
           axis.text.x = element_text(angle=0, vjust=1),
           axis.title=element_text(size=16), 
           legend.position="bottom", legend.direction = "vertical", #change location and direction of legend
           legend.text = element_text(colour="blue", size = 16, face = "bold"))+  #change style for legend text
     theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18))+
     ylim(c(0,1)) + xlim(c(0,25))
```